# Android Append text to file not working even if fileOutputStream appending mode setted to TRUE

Tags: android, file, append, storage

I am trying to append text into a file stored in **emulated/0/..** folder (external storage without SD Card)

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(capturesFile, true);
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);
String data = "my data";
writer.append(data);
writer.close();
fileOutputStream.flush();
fileOutputStream.close();
```

This code is not working, I really do not understand why. Is the emulated location is a problem (stupid question but at this point...) I already tried many ways without any positive solution.

Is someone have an idea about this issue.

Comment: what happen exactly? Your text is not appended?

Comment: Yes it s not appending.

Comment: Try use FileWriter instead. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("path/of/file",true);
        fw.write("myData");
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Yes it is working. I don't understand why the OutputStreamWriter  is not appending. Do you know how i could create a folder into the internal root storage ROOT/MyFolder/Myfiles like does many applications ?

Comment: Yes , for create a folder use this         File folder = new File("path/of/folder");
        folder.mkdirs();

Comment: Yes sure :) i used this object constructor and the mkdirs method. Simply it not creates any folder in the internal storage root. No exception is thrown when mkdirs is called. It's why i asked, i guess there is a tricky thing to do but which one ?

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierPignon mkdirs method return a boolean , it's true or false? Are you added inside manifest WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission? Are you checked if permission is allowed?

Comment: Finally found why i can't create it, it was the way i created the path. Now it s working perfectly. Thank you for the file appending :)

Answer (score 0):

1. First make sure you've given the required permission to write a file and that would be -

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   ```

in Manifest file and

```
   if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE_EXT_STORAGE);
    }
```

in your activity.

2. Second please check your directory path. There might be some chances that you are using a wrong path. Easiest way to get a direct path for the Internal Storage is -

   ```
   String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/data" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
   File file = new File(path + "/File.txt");
   ```
3. You can use this method as per your requirement to write a file -

   ```
   try {
       OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));
       outputStreamWriter.append("My Data");
       outputStreamWriter.flush();
       outputStreamWriter.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for ur time. Sure i gave the permission and ckecked them, the problem is not to write a file in emulated/0 but to append data into the file. It only writes once. After no data are appended. That s my first problem, i already tried many ways. I can t explain . My second wish is to write into a folder like does Whatsapp and others app into the root folder.

Comment: Thank you for your help i really appreciate it. However, your update just change the folder. Anyway, the file is still not appending, i really don't understand why, it's a puzzle. About the folder, i used Android/data because i didn t find the way to create one on the internal root like does many applications (Snapchat, whatsapp etc) If they can do I hope i can also